# Python assert isinstance() Vector

Tags: python, assert, duck-typing, isinstance

I am trying to implement a Vector3 class in python. If I would write the Vector3 class in c++ or c# i would have X, Y, and Z members stored as floats but in python I read that ducktyping is the way to go. So according to my c++/c# knowledge I wrote something like this:

```
class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0):
        assert (isinstance(x, float) or isinstance(x, int)) and (isinstance(y, float) or isinstance(y, int)) and \
               (isinstance(z, float) or isinstance(z, int))
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)
```

The question is regarding the assert statements: Would you use them or not in this instance (a Vector3 implementation for math). I also used it for the operations like

```
def __add__(self, other):
    assert isinstance(other, Vector3)
    return Vector3(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
```

Would you use assert in these instances or not? 
According to this website : https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively it should not be overused but for me as someone who used static typing all along, not checking for the same datatype is extremely weird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`assert` is better used for debugging than left loafing around in production code. You can instead create properties for the vector attributes `x`, `y` and `z`, and **`raise ValueError`** when the passed values are not of the required type:

```
class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('Inappropriate type: {} for x whereas a float \
            or int is expected'.format(type(val)))
        self._x = float(val)

    ...
```

Notice how `isinstance` also takes a tuple of types.

In the `__add__` operator, you'll want to `raise TypeError` also, including an appropriate message:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Vector3):
        raise TypeError('Object of type Vector3 expected, \
        however type {} was passed'.format(type(other)))
    ...
```

Comment: So You would also use isinstance() in that example and not just expect the right type right away?

Comment: @StefanB You can, to prevent users from passing other numeric types such as complex types.